# Onchange Error: undefined (setting 'value')

Tags: javascript, html, undefined, onchange, html-datalist

I am asking for help, I have a problem because I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')" on my console. I can't use document.getElementByID because my ID will change, it must be class. Could someone help me what needs to be changed in this code?

```js
function information(ele){
 
for(var i=0; i<30; i++){
 var address1 = document.getElementsByClassName('test2')[i];

  if( ele.value == "test4"){
    address1.value = "test5";
  } else if (ele.value == "test6"){
    address1.value = "test7";
  } else if (ele.value == "test8"){
    address1.value = "test9";
  }
}
}
```

```html
<div class="form grup information">
  <lable for="dates-full.names"> Names full</lable>
  <input name="dates-full.names" list="dates-full.names" type="text"
    class="form grup test1" onchange="information(this)">
  <datalist type="text" id="dates-full.names">
    <option value="test4">
    <option value="test6">
    <option value="test8">
  </datalist>
</div>


<div class="form grup test2">
  <lable for="power-full.adress"> Adress full</lable>
  <input id="test2" name="dates-full.adress" list="dates-full.adress" type="text"
  class="form grup test2">
  <datalist type="text" id="dates-full.adress">
    <option value="test5">
    <option value="test7">
    <option value="test9">
  </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: You're assuming you have 30 elements with the class `test2`, but you don't. Also you're calling the class selector and retrieving all those elements for each iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function information(ele){
  var address1 = document.getElementsByClassName('test2');
  for(var i=0; i<address1.length; i++){
    if( ele.value == "test4"){
      address1[i].value = "test5";
    } else if (ele.value == "test6"){
      address1[i].value = "test7";
    } else if (ele.value == "test8"){
      address1[i].value = "test9";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no 30 elements with class name `'test2'`. In your for loop, you iterate over 30 possible elements, and then you search for the nth element with class name `'test2'`. Yet there might be less than 30 elements. Iterating over non existent elements.

A possible solution to this would be to do a foreach instead of a for. Iterating over all the elements.

Try these:
[For-each over an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).